# How to get a for loops texts on one line?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to get a for loops text on one line and not print on the second, thrid, fourth, etc.

```pascal
procedure TFormQ1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b, c, I: integer;
begin

  a := SpinEdit1.Value;

  for I := 1 to a do
  begin

    if a mod I = 0 then
    begin

    memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(I));

    end;
  end;
end;
```

I expect the output to be the multiples of a number that i have input on one line.strong text

Comment: could you give an example (math) with input and output

Comment: Use a string variable to concatenate the values from the loop, then as a final step add that string to the memo

Comment: Why use a memo control for a single line of text?

Comment: Perhaps ist should be `if (I mod a) = 0 then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By its very name, `Lines.Add()` adds a new line. To avoid that, simply don't use `Lines.Add()` on every loop iteration. There are a few different ways you can approach this to put everything on one line:

```
for I := 1 to a do begin 
  ...
  memo1.Text := memo1.Text + IntToStr(I);
  ...
end;
```

```
var
  ...
  s: string;
begin
  ...
  for I := 1 to a do begin 
    ...
    s := s + IntToStr(I);
    ...
  end;
  memo1.Text := s; // or memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  ...
end;
```

```
var
  ...
  Idx: integer;
begin
  ... 
  Idx := memo1.Lines.Add('');
  for I := 1 to a do begin 
    ...
    memo1.Lines[Idx] := memo1.Lines[Idx] + IntToStr(I);
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

```
var
  ...
  len: integer;
begin
  ...
  for I := 1 to a do begin 
    ...
    {memo1.SelStart := memo1.GetTextLen;
    memo1.SelLength := 0;}
    len := memo1.GetTextLen;
    memo1.Perform(EM_SETSEL, len, len);
    memo1.SelText := IntToStr(I);
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Since `Memo.Lines` is `TStrings` object why not access each individual line as `Memo1.Lines[L] := Memo1.Lines[L]+' '+IntToStr(I);` where `L` is the number of line to whom you may want to append some additional text

Comment: @SilverWarior that is another option. I have updated my answer